# What is $f^TAf$ intuitively

Tags: linear-algebra

I can get from the definition of matrix production that the result of the formula is $\Sigma_{i=0}^nf_ia_{ij}f_j$. But is there any physical interpretation of this formula, like some sort of transformation or something?

Or, I want to ask, $f^Tf$ is the inner product, and what is the position of square matrix $A$ in this.

PS: $f$ is a column vector.

Comment: You could think of this as a generalization of the dot product if $A$ is the metric tensor on some surface.

Comment: You can somewhat think of this as a "warping" of the dot product. Loosely the value tells you the "orientation" of $Af$ with respect to $f$ (if you neglect sizes).

Comment: it would be nice if either Kevin Driscoll or Cameron Williams (or both) could translate their comments in an answer: both of them are quite interesting.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll A more detailed description would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok imagine we work with some physical system which has some unique geometry that it is natural to choose different coordinate system than standard Cartesian coordinate system. But we need to measure **physical** quantities which can be measured easily in Cartesian coordinate frame.

So if we have vector $v$ in special coordinate system than to measure it's **real** length we have to transform it back to the real physical world by matrix $A$ where we can measure it's length. 
So
$$
\|v\|_{\text{physical length}}^2 = \|Av\|^2_2 = v^TA^TAv = v^TBv
$$
for $B = A^TA$.

Now I give you an example. Let's have piece of rubber, which will undergo some deformations. It is natural to describe this piece of rubber in it's rest state(reference frame), so you refer to pieces of rubber as places where they were in rest state. But as time passes and rubber gets deformed and distance between two pieces doesn't stays the same.

So you have two points in rubber $a,b$ their distance is $\|a-b\|$ in time zero, when there is no deformation. As time passes these points move around but we still refer to them as where they were in time zero. So if we want to calculate distance between them we have to transform point $a,b$ to their actual position and calculate distances between them. So 
$$
\|a-b\|_{\text{ in time } t} = \|A(t)(a-b)\|_2 = (a-b)^TA^TA(a-b)
$$
where $A(t)$ describes the deformation in time $t$.

This example with rubber is a little bit more complicated because in general we work in nonuniformly deformed space so this to work points $a,b$ has to be very close together. But I hope I got the message over what $v^TAv$ means.

In summary: That sometimes it is natural to describe our system in different coordinate frame that the physical one, but we have to be careful and take our measurements in the right physical frame.